# Lua - Filter Forge - Simplex Noise: Need help troubleshooting 'attempt to index a nil value (local 'grd')'

Tags: arrays, lua, noise, simplex

I'll get the ball rolling with this: I converted Simplex noise written in `java` to `lua` and found myself caught on a potential out of bounds error being reported as an attempt to index a `nil` value. I've commented out most of the code and focused on one point where I could no longer adequately test the problem. I've put a couple days into this, so it's time to put it out there for someone else to look at. It could be obvious to a more experienced author what I'm missing. If you give it a look, you have my gratitude!

Code

```
--
-- simplex noise proto.lua
-- v.0.0.1 revision and testing
-- generates simplex noise in 2d, 3d and 4d
-- source: https://weber.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/SimplexNoise.java
-- used in filter forge map script component

--[[
   Simplex noise is a type of gradient noise that is used for generating natural-looking textures, terrain,
   and other procedural content.
   A speed-improved simplex noise algorithm for 2D, 3D and 4D in Lua.

   Based on example code by Stefan Gustavson (stegu@itn.liu.se).
   Optimisations by Peter Eastman (peastman@drizzle.stanford.edu).
   Lua conversion by David Bryan Roberson (https://github.com/eyeofparadox) in 2023
   Better rank ordering method for 4D by Stefan Gustavson in 2012.

   This could be speeded up even further, but it's useful as it is.

   Version 2012-03-09-2023

   This code was placed in the public domain by its original author,
   Stefan Gustavson. You may use it as you see fit, but attribution is appreciated.
--]]

function prepare()
   -- inputs and precalculation.
   noiseScale = 50
   noiseOctaves = 4
   noiseLacunarity = 2.0
   noisePersistence = 0.5

   grad3 = {
      {1,1,0},{-1,1,0},{1,-1,0},{-1,-1,0},
      {1,0,1},{-1,0,1},{1,0,-1},{-1,0,-1},
      {0,1,1},{0,-1,1},{0,1,-1},{0,-1,-1}
   }

   grad4 = {
      {0, 1, 1, 1},   {0, 1, 1, -1},   {0, 1, -1, 1},   {0, 1, -1, -1},
      {0, -1, 1, 1}, {0, -1, 1, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 1}, {0, -1, -1, -1},
      {1, 0, 1, 1},   {1, 0, 1, -1},   {1, 0, -1, 1},   {1, 0, -1, -1},
      {-1, 0, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1, -1}, {-1, 0, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1, -1},
      {1, 1, 0, 1},   {1, 1, 0, -1},   {1, -1, 0, 1},   {1, -1, 0, -1},
      {-1, 1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 0, -1}, {-1, -1, 0, 1}, {-1, -1, 0, -1},
      {1, 1, 1, 0},   {1, 1, -1, 0},   {1, -1, 1, 0},   {1, -1, -1, 0},
      {-1, 1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, 0}
   }

   p = {
      151,160,137,91,90,15,
      131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
      190,6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
      88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168,68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
      77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
      102,143,54,65,25,63,161,1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208,89,18,169,200,196,
      135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186,3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
      5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
      223,183,170,213,119,248,152,2,44,154,163,70,221,153,101,155,167,43,172,9,
      129,22,39,253,19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185,112,104,218,246,97,228,
      251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241,81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
      49,192,214,31,181,199,106,157,184,84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127,4,150,254,
      138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180
   }

   n = #p

   perm = {}
   -- initialize permutation table with random values
   for i=1,256 do
      perm[i] = math.random(0,255)
   end

   -- extend the permutation table to avoid overflow
   for i=257,512 do
      perm[i] = perm[i - 256]
   end

   permMod12 = {}
   -- initialize permMod12 table with 0 values
   for i = 1, 512 do
      permMod12[i] = 0
   end
   
   for i=1,512 do
      permMod12[i] = perm[i] % 12
   end

   -- update grad3 and grad4 with the new permutation table
   -- for i=1,256 do
      -- grad3[i+1] = {grad3[perm[i+1] % 12 + 1][1], grad3[perm[i+1] % 12 + 1][2], grad3[perm[i+1] % 12 + 1][3]}
      -- grad4[i+1] = {grad4[perm[i+1] % 32 + 1][1], grad4[perm[i+1] % 32 + 1][2], grad4[perm[i+1] % 32 + 1][3], grad4[perm[i+1] % 32 + 1][4]}
   -- end

   F2 = 0.5*(math.sqrt(3.0)-1.0)
   G2 = (3.0-math.sqrt(3.0))/6.0
   F3 = 1.0/3.0
   G3 = 1.0/6.0
   F4 = (math.sqrt(5.0)-1.0)/4.0
   G4 = (5.0-math.sqrt(5.0))/20.0
end;


function get_sample(x, y)
               if x < 0 or x > 1 or y < 0 or y > 1 then
                  return 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
               end
   local xin, yin = x/noiseScale, y/noiseScale
   local noise2D = get_2d_noise(xin, yin, noiseOctaves, noiseLacunarity, noisePersistence)
   -- local noise3D = 0 -- get_3d_noise(xin, yin, 0, noiseOctaves, noiseLacunarity, noisePersistence)
   -- local noise4D = 0 -- get_4d_noise(xin, yin, 0, 0, noiseOctaves, noiseLacunarity, noisePersistence)

   local r = noise2D
   -- local g = noise3D
   -- local b = noise4D
   local a = 1

   -- return r, g, b, a
   return r, 0, 0, a
   -- return 0, g, 0, a
   -- return 0, 0, b, a
end

function test_variables(r, g, b, a)
  local variables = {r, g, b, a}
  local nil_values = false
  
  for i=1, 4 do
    if variables[i] == nil then
      variables[i] = 0
      nil_values = true
    elseif variables[i] ~= nil then
      variables[i] = variables[i]
    else
      variables[i] = 1
      nil_values = true
    end
  end
  
  if nil_values then
    return unpack(variables)
  end
end

--[[
function grad3(...)
   local args = {...}
   for i, x in ipairs(args) do
      args[i] = x % n
   end
   local a = args[1] + args[2] + args[3]
   local gi = permMod12[a % n]
   -- for i in `grad3`
   if grad3[i] == nil then
     return 1, 0, 1, 1
   end
   return dot({grad3[gi][1], grad3[gi][2], grad3[gi][3]}, args[1] - grad3[a % 12 + 1][1], args[2] - grad3[a % 12 + 1][2], args[3] - grad3[a % 12 + 1][3])
end

function grad4(...)
   local args = {...}
   for i, x in ipairs(args) do
      args[i] = x % n
   end
   local a = args[1] + args[2] + args[3] + args[4]
   local gi = permMod12[a % n]
   -- for i in `grad4`
   if grad4[i] == nil then
     return 1, 0, 1, 1
   end
   return dot({grad4[gi][1], grad4[gi][2], grad4[gi][3], grad4[gi][4]}, args[1] - grad4[a % 32 + 1][1], args[2] - grad4[a % 32 + 1][2], args[3] - grad4[a % 32 + 1][3], args[4] - grad4[a % 32 + 1][4])
end
]]--

function fastfloor(x)
   local xi = math.floor(x)
   return (x < xi) and (xi-1) or xi
end

function dot(grd, x, y)
   return (grd.x*x) + (grd.y*y) -- debug "Script error (line 141) : attempt to index a nil value (local 'grd')" >>> called from: lines 215,222,229
end

-- function dot(grd, x, y, z)
   -- return (grd.x*x) + (grd.y*y) + (grd.z*z)
-- end

-- function dot(grd, x, y, z, w)
   -- return (grd.x*x) + (grd.y*y) + (grd.z*z) + (grd.w*w)
-- end

function get_2d_noise(xin, yin)
   local n0, n1, n2
   
   local s = (xin+yin)*F2
   local i = fastfloor(xin+s)
   local j = fastfloor(yin+s)
   local t = (i+j)*G2
   local x0 = i-t
   local y0 = j-t
   local x0 = xin-x0
   local y0 = yin-y0
   
   local i1, j1
   if x0>y0 then
      i1 = 1
      j1 = 0
   else
      i1 = 0
      j1 = 1
   end
   
   local x1 = x0 - i1 + G2
   local y1 = y0 - j1 + G2
   local x2 = x0 - 1.0 + 2.0 * G2
   local y2 = y0 - 1.0 + 2.0 * G2
   
   local ii = (i + 1) & 255
   local jj = (j + 1) & 255
   test_variables(ii,jj)

   local gi0 = permMod12[ii+perm[jj]]
   local gi1 = permMod12[ii+i1+perm[jj+j1]]
   local gi2 = permMod12[ii+1+perm[jj+1]]
   test_variables(gi0,gi1,gi2)
   
   local t0 = 0.5 - x0*x0-y0*y0
   if t0<0 then
      n0 = 0.0
   else
      t0 = t0 * t0
      n0 = t0 * t0 * dot(grad3[gi0], x0, y0) -- <<< grad3[gi0],grad3[gi1],grad3[gi2] may be `nil`: points at lines 206-208 again
   end
   local t1 = 0.5 - x1*x1-y1*y1
   if t1<0 then
      n1 = 0.0
   else
      t1 = t1 * t1
      n1 = t1 * t1 * dot(grad3[gi1], x1, y1)
   end
   local t2 = 0.5 - x2*x2-y2*y2
   if t2<0 then
      n2 = 0.0
   else
      t2 = t2 * t2
      n2 = t2 * t2 * dot(grad3[gi2], x2, y2)
   end
   
   return  (n0 + n1 + n2)
   -- return 70.0 * (n0 + n1 + n2)
end

   --[[
function get_3d_noise(xin, yin, zin)
   local n0, n1, n2, n3
   local s = (xin+yin+zin)*F3
   local i = math.floor(xin+s)
   local j = math.floor(yin+s)
   local k = math.floor(zin+s)
   local t = (i+j+k)*G3
   local x0 = i-t
   local y0 = j-t
   local z0 = k-t
   local x0 = xin-x0
   local y0 = yin-y0
   local z0 = zin-z0
   local i1, j1, k1
   local i2, j2, k2
   if x0>=y0 then
      if y0>=z0 then
         i1=1; j1=0; k1=0; i2=1; j2=1; k2=0
      elseif x0>=z0 then
         i1=1; j1=0; k1=0; i2=1; j2=0; k2=1
      else
         i1=0; j1=0; k1=1; i2=1; j2=0; k2=1
      end
   else -- x0<y0
      if y0<z0 then
         i1=0; j1=0; k1=1; i2=0; j2=1; k2=1
      elseif x0<z0 then
         i1=0; j1=1; k1=0; i2=0; j2=1; k2=1
      else
         i1=0; j1=1; k1=0; i2=1; j2=1; k2=0
      end
   end
   local x1 = x0 - i1 + G3
   local y1 = y0 - j1 + G3
   local z1 = z0 - k1 + G3
   local x2 = x0 - i2 + 2.0*G3
   local y2 = y0 - j2 + 2.0*G3
   local z2 = z0 - k2 + 2.0*G3
   local x3 = x0 - 1.0 + 3.0*G3
   local y3 = y0 - 1.0 + 3.0*G3
   local z3 = z0 - 1.0 + 3.0*G3
   local ii = (i + 1) & 255
   local jj = (j + 1) & 255
   local kk = (k + 1) & 255
   -- in `get_3d_noise`
   if not ii or jj or kk then
      return 0, 1, 0, 1
   end
   -- local gi0 = permMod12[ii+perm[jj+perm[kk+1] ]
   local gi1 = permMod12[ii+i1+perm[jj+j1+perm[kk+k1+1] ]
   local gi2 = permMod12[ii+i2+perm[jj+j2+perm[kk+k2+1] ]
   local gi3 = permMod12[ii+1+perm[jj+1+perm[kk+1+1] ]
   local t0 = 0.6 - x0*x0 - y0*y0 - z0*z0
   if t0<0 then n0 = 0.0 else
      t0 = t0 * t0
      n0 = t0 * t0 * dot(grad3[gi0], x0, y0, z0)
   end
   local t1 = 0.6 - x1*x1 - y1*y1 - z1*z1
   if t1<0 then n1 = 0.0 else
      t1 = t1 * t1
      n1 = t1 * t1 * dot(grad3[gi1], x1, y1, z1)
   end
   local t2 = 0.6 - x2*x2 - y2*y2 - z2*z2
   if t2<0 then n2 = 0.0 else
      t2 = t2 * t2
      n2 = t2 * t2 * dot(grad3[gi2], x2, y2, z2)
   end
   local t3 = 0.6 - x3*x3 - y3*y3 - z3*z3
   if t3<0 then n3 = 0.0 else
      t3 = t3 * t3
      n3 = t3 * t3 * dot(grad3[gi3], x3, y3, z3)
   end
   return 32.0*(n0 + n1 + n2 + n3)
end

function get_4d_noise(x, y, z, w)
   local n0, n1, n2, n3, n4
   local s = (x + y + z + w) * F4
   local i = math.floor(x + s)
   local j = math.floor(y + s)
   local k = math.floor(z + s)
   local l = math.floor(w + s)
   local t = (i + j + k + l) * G4
   local x0 = i - t -- unskew the cell origin back to (x,y,z,w) space
   local y0 = j - t
   local z0 = k - t
   local w0 = l - t
   local x0 = x - x0
   local y0 = y - y0
   local z0 = z - z0
   local w0 = w - w0
   local rankx = 0
   local ranky = 0
   local rankz = 0
   local rankw = 0
   if x0 > y0 then
      rankx = rankx + 1
   else
      ranky = ranky + 1
   end
   if x0 > z0 then
      rankx = rankx + 1
   else
      rankz = rankz + 1
   end
   if x0 > w0 then
      rankx = rankx + 1
   else
      rankw = rankw + 1
   end
   if y0 > z0 then
      ranky = ranky + 1
   else
      rankz = rankz + 1
   end
   if y0 > w0 then
      ranky = ranky + 1
   else
      rankw = rankw + 1
   end
   if z0 > w0 then
      rankz = rankz + 1
   else
      rankw = rankw + 1
   end
   local i1, j1, k1, l1
   local i2, j2, k2, l2
   local i3, j3, k3, l3
   i1 = (rankx >= 3) and 1 or 0
   j1 = (ranky >= 3) and 1 or 0
   k1 = (rankz >= 3) and 1 or 0
   l1 = (rankw >= 3) and 1 or 0
   i2 = (rankx >= 2) and 1 or 0
   j2 = (ranky >= 2) and 1 or 0
   k2 = (rankz >= 2) and 1 or 0
   l2 = (rankw >= 2) and 1 or 0
   i3 = (rankx >= 1) and 1 or 0
   j3 = (ranky >= 1) and 1 or 0
   k3 = (rankz >= 1) and 1 or 0
   l3 = (rankw >= 1) and 1 or 0
   local x1 = x0 - i1 + G4
   local y1 = y0 - j1 + G4
   local z1 = z0 - k1 + G4
   local w1 = w0 - l1 + G4
   local x2 = x0 - i2 + 2.0*G4
   local y2 = y0 - j2 + 2.0*G4
   local z2 = z0 - k2 + 2.0*G4
   local w2 = w0 - l2 + 2.0*G4
   local x3 = x0 - i3 + 3.0*G4
   local y3 = y0 - j3 + 3.0*G4
   local z3 = z0 - k3 + 3.0*G4
   local w3 = w0 - l3 + 3.0*G4
   local x4 = x0 - 1.0 + 4.0*G4
   local y4 = y0 - 1.0 + 4.0*G4
   local z4 = z0 - 1.0 + 4.0*G4
   local w4 = w0 - 1.0 + 4.0*G4
   local ii = (i + 1) & 255
   local jj = (j + 1) & 255
   local kk = (k + 1) & 255
   local ll = (l + 1) & 255
   -- in `get_4d_noise`
   if not ii or jj or kk or ll then
      return 0, 0, 1, 1
   end
   local gi0 = perm[ii+perm[jj+perm[kk+perm[ll] ] ] ] & 31
   local gi1 = perm[ii+i1+perm[jj+j1+perm[kk+k1+perm[ll+l1] ] ] ] & 31
   local gi2 = perm[ii+i2+perm[jj+j2+perm[kk+k2+perm[ll+l2] ] ] ] & 31
   local gi3 = perm[ii+i3+perm[jj+j3+perm[kk+k3+perm[ll+l3] ] ] ] & 31
   local gi4 = perm[ii+1+perm[jj+1+perm[kk+1+perm[ll+1] ] ] ] & 31
   local t0 = 0.6 - x0*x0 - y0*y0 - z0*z0 - w0*w0
   if t0 < 0 then
      n0 = 0.0
   else
      t0 = t0 * t0
      n0 = t0 * t0 * dot(grad4[gi0], x0, y0, z0, w0);
      -- n0 = t0 * t0 * (x0 * grad4[gi0].x + y0 * grad4[gi0].y + z0 * grad4[gi0].z + w0 * grad4[gi0].w)
   end
   local t1 = 0.6 - x1*x1 - y1*y1 - z1*z1 - w1*w1
   if t1 < 0 then
      n1 = 0.0
   else
      t1 = t1 * t1
      n1 = t1 * t1 * dot(grad4[gi1], x1, y1, z1, w1);
      -- n1 = t1 * t1 * (x1 * grad4[gi1].x + y1 * grad4[gi1].y + z1 * grad4[gi1].z + w1 * grad4[gi1].w)
   end
   local t2 = 0.6 - x2*x2 - y2*y2 - z2*z2 - w2*w2
   if t2 < 0 then
      n2 = 0.0
   else
      t2 = t2 * t2
      n2 = t2 * t2 * dot(grad4[gi2], x2, y2, z2, w2);
      -- n2 = t2 * t2 * (x2 * grad4[gi2].x + y2 * grad4[gi2].y + z2 * grad4[gi2].z + w2 * grad4[gi2].w)
   end
   local t3 = 0.6 - x3*x3 - y3*y3 - z3*z3 - w3*w3
   if t3 < 0 then
      n3 = 0.0
   else
      t3 = t3 * t3
      n3 = t3 * t3 * dot(grad4[gi3], x3, y3, z3, w3);
      -- n3 = t3 * t3 * (x3 * grad4[gi3].x + y3 * grad4[gi3].y + z3 * grad4[gi3].z + w3 * grad4[gi3].w)
   end
   local t4 = 0.6 - x4*x4 - y4*y4 - z4*z4 - w4*w4
   if t4 < 0 then
      n4 = 0.0
   else
      t4 = t4 * t4
      n4 = t4 * t4 * dot(grad4[gi4], x4, y4, z4, w4);
      -- n4 = t4 * t4 * (x4 * grad4[gi4].x + y4 * grad4[gi4].y + z4 * grad4[gi4].z + w4 * grad4[gi4].w)
   end
   return 27.0 * (n0 + n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)
end
   ]]--

local grad = {
   x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 0
}

function grad:new(x, y, z)
   local obj = {
      x = x, y = y, z = z
   }
   setmetatable(obj, self)
   self.__index = self
   return obj
end

function grad:new(x, y, z, w)
   local obj = {
      x = x, y = y, z = z, w = w
   }
   setmetatable(obj, self)
   self.__index = self
   return obj
end
```

In Filter Forge, where this script is used in a Map Script component, the coordinates `x`,`y` exist on an infinite plain though the frame of the image is bound between (0,0),(1,1). Point samples made within those bounds are typically also within the standard range of 0,1 but their `r`,`g`,`b`,`a` values can go on infinitely in HDR. I suspect the `nil` value error likely originates from an out-of-bounds access of the `perm` or `permMod12` array, which can occur if the input values for `x` and `y` fall outside the expected range of [0, 1]. Revisions were made to compensate but the error just moved upstream until it reached the `if` at lines 228-233. The tables referenced in lines 222-225 should have been initialized with non `nil` values, so I wonder where the error could be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use 0-indexing from java (to make fewer mistakes in original code). Here is the lua code for the 2d noise. You can easily adapt it for 3d/4d noises (no changes for arrays needed).

```
function prepare()
    noiseScale = 50
   noiseOctaves = 4
   noiseLacunarity = 2.0
   noisePersistence = 0.5

   grad3 = {
      {1,1,0},{-1,1,0},{1,-1,0},{-1,-1,0},
      {1,0,1},{-1,0,1},{1,0,-1},{-1,0,-1},
      {0,1,1},{0,-1,1},{0,1,-1},{0,-1,-1}
   }



  p = {151,160,137,91,90,15,
  131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
  190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
  88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
  77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
  102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
  135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
  5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
  223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
  129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
  251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
  49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
  138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180};

  perm = {};
  permMod12 = {};
  for i = 0, 512 do
    perm[i]=p[(i & 255) + 1];
    -- or with random values -> perm[i]=math.random(0,255)
    permMod12[i] = perm[i] % 12;
  end

  -- Skewing and unskewing factors for 2, 3, and 4 dimensions
  F2 = 0.5*(math.sqrt(3.0)-1.0);
  G2 = (3.0-math.sqrt(3.0))/6.0;
  F3 = 1.0/3.0;
  G3 = 1.0/6.0;
  F4 = (math.sqrt(5.0)-1.0)/4.0;
  G4 = (5.0-math.sqrt(5.0))/20.0;
end;


function get_sample(x, y)
               if x < 0 or x > 1 or y < 0 or y > 1 then
                  return 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
               end
   local xin, yin = x/noiseScale, y/noiseScale
    local noise2D = noise(xin, yin)
   -- local noise3D = 0 -- get_3d_noise(xin, yin, 0, noiseOctaves, noiseLacunarity, noisePersistence)
   -- local noise4D = 0 -- get_4d_noise(xin, yin, 0, 0, noiseOctaves, noiseLacunarity, noisePersistence)

   local r = noise2D * 10
   -- local g = noise3D
   -- local b = noise4D
   local a = 1

   -- return r, g, b, a
   return r, 0, 0, a
   -- return 0, g, 0, a
   -- return 0, 0, b, a
end

-- This method is a *lot* faster than using (int)Math.floor(x)
  function fastfloor(x) 
    local xi = math.floor(x)
    return (x < xi) and (xi-1) or xi
  end

  function dot(g, x, y) 
    return (g[1]*x) + (g[2]*y)
  end


  -- 2D simplex noise
  function noise(xin, yin)
    local n0, n1, n2; -- Noise contributions from the three corners
    -- Skew the input space to determine which simplex cell we're in
    local s = (xin+yin)*F2; -- Hairy factor for 2D
    local i = fastfloor(xin+s);
    local j = fastfloor(yin+s);
    local t = (i+j)*G2;
    local X0 = i-t; -- Unskew the cell origin back to (x,y) space
    local Y0 = j-t;
    local x0 = xin-X0; -- The x,y distances from the cell origin
    local y0 = yin-Y0;
    -- For the 2D case, the simplex shape is an equilateral triangle.
    -- Determine which simplex we are in.
    local i1, j1; -- Offsets for second (middle) corner of simplex in (i,j) coords
    if x0>y0 then
      i1=1; 
      j1=0; -- lower triangle, XY order: (0,0)->(1,0)->(1,1)
    else 
      i1=0; 
      j1=1;
    end      -- upper triangle, YX order: (0,0)->(0,1)->(1,1)
    -- A step of (1,0) in (i,j) means a step of (1-c,-c) in (x,y), and
    -- a step of (0,1) in (i,j) means a step of (-c,1-c) in (x,y), where
    -- c = (3-sqrt(3))/6
    local x1 = x0 - i1 + G2; -- Offsets for middle corner in (x,y) unskewed coords
    local y1 = y0 - j1 + G2;
    local x2 = x0 - 1.0 + 2.0 * G2; -- Offsets for last corner in (x,y) unskewed coords
    local y2 = y0 - 1.0 + 2.0 * G2;
    -- Work out the hashed gradient indices of the three simplex corners
    local ii = i & 255;
    local jj = j & 255;
    local gi0 = permMod12[ii+perm[jj]];
    local gi1 = permMod12[ii+i1+perm[jj+j1]];
    local gi2 = permMod12[ii+1+perm[jj+1]];
    -- Calculate the contribution from the three corners
    local t0 = 0.5 - x0*x0-y0*y0;
    if t0<0 then
     n0 = 0.0;
    else 
      t0 = t0 * t0;
      n0 = t0 * t0 * dot(grad3[gi0], x0, y0);  -- (x,y) of grad3 used for 2D gradient
    end
    local t1 = 0.5 - x1*x1-y1*y1;
    if t1<0 then
     n1 = 0.0;
    else 
      t1 = t1 * t1;
      n1 = t1 * t1 * dot(grad3[gi1], x1, y1);
    end
    local t2 = 0.5 - x2*x2-y2*y2;
    if t2<0 then
      n2 = 0.0;
    else 
      t2 = t2 * t2;
      n2 = t2 * t2 * dot(grad3[gi2], x2, y2);
    end
    -- Add contributions from each corner to get the final noise value.
    -- The result is scaled to return values in the interval [-1,1].
    return 70.0 * (n0 + n1 + n2);
  end
```

Here is the result of lua script in Filter Forge:
[image]